# d3 add line to existing plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating scatterplots with D3 and want to superimpose some lines (a boxplot, eventually). I'm totally failing to append any line to the plots and don't get why. The code below is just one attempt of many.

I've searched and found various solutions, but haven't managed to get any of them to work. I'd be grateful of any help.

```
svg[i].selectAll(".dot")
.data(thedata)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 4.5)
.attr("cx", xMap)
.attr("cy", yMap)
.style("fill", "steelblue");

// Try to add arbitrary line            
svg[i].append("line")
.attr("x1", 0)
.attr("x2", 3)
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("y2", 4);
```

In case it's of interest, the use case is here: https://goo.gl/nbVfvu

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing style attribute for the line, add style attribute for the line. Example as below.

```
svg[i]
.append("line")
.attr("x1",30)
.attr("y1",20)
.attr("x2",11)
.attr("y2",1)
.style("stroke", "black")
```

Comment: Agh! Of all the combinations of stuff I tried, I somehow never managed it just like that . Thanks!